# Unable to load the image from CSS file URL

Tags: css, image, loading

I just started learning about web development and I got this issue about loading image from CSS file. I already tried many solutions that I can find in stack overflow but still doesn't work.

I tried to click on the URL: `images/banner.jpg` on vs code but it said: an error occur while loading an image. But then when I try to use the same path with `<img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="banner">`, it still loads
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHVmA.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url: _"Relative URLs, if used, are relative to the URL of the stylesheet (not to the URL of the web page)."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to set `../` in image path like below:

```
background: url(../images/banner.jpg);
```